# MySQL ADD_DATE timezone issue

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, dateadd

I store events with Unix Time-stamp on my database
When i want to fetch them as datetime in MySQL with `FROM_UNIXTIME` or `DATE_ADD` functions different values generated right equal to timezone of my current location (UTC +3:30). **I have to use `DATE_ADD` function because the `FROM_UNIXTIME` doesn't work for negative timestamps.** how can I fix this problem?!
Thanks all in advance.

Here it is my Query:

```
SELECT topic, `start`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`start`), DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 1:0:0', INTERVAL `start` SECOND) FROM uzr_event
```

And here it is Answer:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2h8A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your result is offset is because the string you're passing to `DATE_ADD` is being interpreted by the session time zone, rather than UTC.

You can either do this before your query:

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Or you can leave the session time zone out of the equation and just change this:

```
DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 1:0:0', INTERVAL `start` SECOND)
```

To this:

```
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL `start` SECOND)
```